# Joining Child table of Child table in TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I have these entities and want to get data of only `attendance` and join `breakAcknowledgement` for related break of attendance. How can I query this without using querybuilder. I want to use TypeORM Entity manager.

[image: database]

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Also, share the error stacktrace. Read the entire [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) page.

Comment: @EmptyBrain, I am new to NestJs, and this is the first time I  am coding in NestJS so no. I have not got satisfactory answer to my problem online. that is why i asked it here.

Comment: I am joining tables using ```      join: {
        alias: 'attendance',
        leftJoinAndSelect: {
          user: 'attendance.user',
          outlet: 'attendance.outlet',
          punchAck: 'attendance.punchAck',
        }``` but as I have already mentioned , there is no direct link between two tables.